# Use libc++ on Windows?

Tags: clang, llvm

Does libc++ support to be referenced/included and compiled on Windows with Clang/LLVM as native? For native, I mean no dependence on mingw and cygwin. I didn't find much doc on this but I believe it should be supported as clang for Windows has been released for a long time.

Comment: Probably not. I have tried this a year ago or so and had lots of troubles compiling libc++-abi due to lack of exception support.

Comment: I've been trying to get Clang to work on Windows as well. Clang for Windows has been released in the form of ready-made windows install packages, see [here](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html). If I'm not mistaken, it requires MSVC's linker and stdlib though, and that's the reason I'm not using it.

Answer (score 10):

Just an update. There is experimental support now (early 2018):

https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/BuildingLibcxx.html#experimental-support-for-windows

(from the link)

Assming you have Ninja, and libcxx/llvm both checked out, libcxx can be compiled via

```
> cmake -G Ninja                                                                    ^
        -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/path/to/ninja                                         ^
        -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Windows                                                 ^
        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-cl                                                 ^
        -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fms-compatibility-version=19.00 --target=i686--windows"   ^
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang-cl                                                ^
        -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fms-compatibility-version=19.00 --target=i686--windows" ^
        -DLLVM_PATH=/path/to/llvm/tree                                              ^
        -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED=YES                                                  ^
        -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_STATIC=NO                                                   ^
        -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_LIBRARY=NO                                     ^
        \path\to\libcxx
> /path/to/ninja cxx
```

As of 4/23/18, it will install into Program Files (x86) even if compiled for x86-64... (which can be done by changing i686 to x86_64 in the above).

**Update in November 2020: I now use a package called [llvm-mingw](https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw).**

This package includes the clang compiler toolchain with wrappers to support various gcc style executables (e.g. gcc.exe, g++.exe, x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe) and can be used out of the box to compile against the mingw libc++ (you don't have to install mingw separately, the mingw libraries come with the package).

llvm-mingw is still young but has most features of mingw-w64. Features that are not implemented are:

- lld linking to a dll (it's a feature of gnu ld, but not the llvm implementation)
- There is no python wrapper for lldb so many IDEs can't use the debugger. Visual Studio Code seems to have it's own linkage so LLDB soes work with VS Code. People are working on this now.

Releases are available at the authors github repo. I have a binary installer available at my [winlua.net](http://winlua.net) site.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @IronManMark20

Comment: Since February '21 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/995a128f07b60e82fdf7eb1e13670b4cda992379) Windows support is no longer marked as experimental: https://libcxx.llvm.org//BuildingLibcxx.html#support-for-windows

Answer (score 9):

One can build and install `libc++` together with `clang` in Windows by setting `LLVM_FORCE_BUILD_RUNTIME` cmake's variable to `ON`. Here is an example:

```
cmake -Wno-dev -G Ninja
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:\clang
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_Z3_SOLVER=ON
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS='clang;clang-tools-extra;compiler-rt;libcxx;lld'
    -DLLVM_FORCE_BUILD_RUNTIME=ON
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-cl
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang-cl
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GS- /GR /EHsc /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL_DEPRECATE=0 /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /D_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0 /DSTRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE'
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE='/MD /clang:-march=native /clang:-mtune=native /clang:-O3 /clang:-g0 /DNDEBUG'
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS='/GS- /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL_DEPRECATE=0 /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DSTRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE'
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE='/MD /clang:-march=native /clang:-mtune=native /clang:-O3 /clang:-g0 /DNDEBUG'
    ..\llvm-project\llvm
```

However, there is a catch. Clang driver in Windows still doesn't support `libc++`, so you have to manually add the header files directory and `c++.lib`, if you want to use `libc++`. If you take a look at the Clang's driver source code, there is a line left there 9 years ago:

```cpp
void MSVCToolChain::AddClangCXXStdlibIncludeArgs(const ArgList &DriverArgs,
                                                 ArgStringList &CC1Args) const {
  // FIXME: There should probably be logic here to find libc++ on Windows.
}
```

It's not a rocket science to add the support, just shows the level of interest to support Windows by the authors.

An example of using `libc++` (after compiling and installing clang with the above cmake example):

```
clang++ -isystem 'c:\clang\include' -isystem 'c:\clang\include\c++\v1' -c .\test.cpp -o test.o
clang++ -fuse-ld=lld test.o -o test.exe -L'c:\clang\lib' -lc++
```